# WKUserScript Init causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

Using XCode 8.2.1, Swift 3.0. When I try to initialize a WKUserScript I get a

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7fff584b7c4)

```
var scriptContent = "alert('hello');"

let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent,
                          injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, 
                          forMainFrameOnly: true)//error here
```

Not sure how to debug this one...

Comment: Does this happen both on device & simulator?

Comment: Yes, just ran on my iPhone and got the same error on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had copied an example and missed that it used a load view override and implemented incorrectly... which was causing errors downstream.

```
override func loadView() {
    //assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the view property here
}
```